# How to Add Maven Properties to banner.txt in Springboot's Common Module?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i'm using springboot 3.0.7.

I created a maven module (name: my-library-banner) where into **src/main/resources** there is file banner.txt

The content of **banner.txt**

```
My Application Banner: ${application.title} ${application.formatted-version}

MyLibraryVersion   (v${banner.version.library})
Spring-Boot        ${spring-boot.formatted-version}
JAVA-VERSION       (v${java.version})
```

Into maven pom.xml there is the property **version.library**

```xml
<properties>
    <version.library>1.0.0</version.library>
</properties>
```

I want to avoid to specify in every application that import my module, into **application.properties** the following property:

```
banner.version.library=@version.library@
```

I tried to create a file `banner-library.properties` with `banner.version.library=@version.library@` inside and tried to include into **application.properties** of childs like this:

```
spring.config.import=classpath:banner-library.properties
```

This works but is annoing to update all configurations.